# How can I use data-confirm with a javascript link_to?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, onclick

I am trying to use data-confirm to intercept a javascript link...

```
link_to "test", "#", :onclick=>"call_js_function(); return false;", :data=>{:confirm=>"are you sure?"}
```

The confirmation appears but the onclick function is being called simultaneously, i.e. it is not getting blocked by the data-confirm.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `confirm` into your function `call_js_function()`.

`call_js_function()` and `data-confirm` don't related to each other.